# Export command not found on mac terminal

Tags: bash, git-bash

Whenever I open my mac terminal it is showing "Export: command not found". Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Below is the issue:

Last login: Sun Jul 26 19:57:04 on ttys000
You have new mail.

```
-bash: Export: command not found
tariq (master #) ~
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
tariq (master #) ~
```

Comment: It should be lowercase `export`, not `Export`

Comment: The problem is in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`.